# A good MCU which supports Arduino library but is not as expensive

Tags: arduino, pcb

I have a prototype working on the Arduino and the application is targeting low cost. So I need to make my own PCB which I am willing to do. But I want to use the Arduino libraries which seem very useful. When I looked at the ATMEGA328p which the Arduino uses it seems to expensive for its price compared to other MCU's out there.

SO I was wondering whats the step I should take. Is there any low cost MCU which AVR themselves make which supports Arduino libraries? The primary requirement is program memory needs to be 32-64kb. So how do I go about targeting low cost and at the same time use existing Arduino libraries so that I don't have to rewrite my code completely?

Comment: Port the Arduino code to not use the Arduino libraries and your application probably fits in a ATtiny. Arduino is nice for building a PoC, for troubleshooting, testing, quick development, but not for low pricing.

Comment: ~$3.00 is expensive? I think you're out of luck then. That's pretty much average.

Comment: you could try to use MSP430G2553 controller from texas instruments.it is compatible with arduino price is very less(even you could ask for free sample). The complete development board costs only ~$10(incl. shipping).

Comment: @yogece The MSP430 is not compatible with Arduino. At best, the Energia libraries for the MSP430 Launchpad provide partial portability of code, but it is still very very limited, hardly good enough for practical direct porting.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh have you actually tried?

Comment: @Passerby Tried what? Energia? Yes, both on the Stellaris and the MSP430. I've been revisiting Energia since the initial builds, since I quite dislike CCS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the ATtiny family of Atmel microcontrollers, and the several tutorials out there for using these MCUs with Arduino code, or a subset of the Arduino libraries.

- Begin with the well-known MIT post on the subject: "[Programming an ATtiny with Arduino](http://hlt.media.mit.edu/?p=1695)"
- Download and study the [Arduino-tiny](https://code.google.com/p/arduino-tiny/) library for ATtiny.
- Follow [this blog](http://toasterbotics.blogspot.in/2011/08/programming-attiny85-arduino-style.html), at ToasterBotics, for another set of inputs on using an ATtiny with Arduino.
- See this Instructable, "[Moving from Arduino to ATtiny and writing your code in pure AVR-C](http://www.instructables.com/id/Honey-I-Shrunk-the-Arduino-Moving-from-Arduino-t/)", for moving to the next level, beyond Arduino library limitations.

Alternatively, consider the very low cost Arduino clones available, for instance this [Arduino Pro Mini clone for $3.56](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1PCS-PRO-Mini-ATMEGA328P-5V-16M-16MHZ-Replace-ATmega128-Arduino-Compatible-Nano-/271300665373?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3f2ac7a01d) including free shipping.

[image: Pro Mini]

You *will* need an additional USB-to-TTL adapter for programming the boards, though.

If you want something inexpensive with an USB connector built in, look at the Arduino Nano clones, [$6.88 with shipping](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Nano-V3-0-ATmega328P-Module-Board-Free-Mini-USB-Cable-Arduino-Compatible-TR-/181188897618?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a2fb32b52):

[image: Nano Clone]

These two options above will save the effort of designing and debugging a new PCB, if they already serve your purpose: They sell fully assembled and operational at prices you cannot hope to match without huge volumes.

Finally, you can also consider moving away from the Atmel family entirely, as others suggest, if you are comfortable with reinvesting sunk effort in learning and coding for a new, cheaper platform.

Comment: You really made me rethink having a board made. I checked out the ebay site. I am unsure as to whether it comes with a bootloader. If it doesnt I can still use another arduino as an ISP right

Comment: @DeveloperAndroid Yes, the two boards I listed both come with bootloader installed, they are ready to run. In general, if this is not so, you can still use another Arduino as an ISP, but would need to install the appropriate boot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use attiny microcontroller and use it on a bread
board, get the hex file generated by arduino and use isp programmer to burn it to the AVR.
[Check this post](http://toasterbotics.blogspot.com/2011/08/programming-attiny85-arduino-style.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Adafruit Trinket; it uses a ATTiny85, and is arduino-compatible.